# IBM MQ Client: Should I commit after each Get to prevent other clients receiving same message

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have C# application that only reads messages from IBM MQ (ver 9.x). I'm calling `MQQueueManager`'s `AccessQueue()` method and then `MQQueue.Get()`, reading messages in a loop and eventually call `queue.Close()`.

I cannot find explicit information whether should I call `MQQueueManager.Commit()` after each messages (or before `queue.Close()` or ever) to be sure that processed messages are not consumed second time by another client, that's connected to the same `queueName`. can someone clarify this for me?

Here are message options: `MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING`

and open options: `MQC.MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQSO_MANAGED | MQC.MQSO_NON_DURABLE | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF`.

Comment: You need to get messages under a SYNC_POINT. If a message is received under a SYNC_POINT, that message will not be available to others till application that received message rolls it back using Rollback call. If you call Comit, the message will be removed from queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat confusing why you are using `MQSO` options for a queue (SO = Subscription Options), however these are just bitwise operations, so you would be getting the results of what the equivalent `MQOO` option is for the same `MQSO`.  See below:

| Bits Options | Sub Options | Equivalent Open Options |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00000000 | MQSO_NONE MQSO_NON_DURABLE MQSO_READ_AHEAD_AS_Q_DEF | MQOO_BIND_AS_Q_DEF MQOO_READ_AHEAD_AS_Q_DEF |
| 0x00000001 | MQSO_ALTER | MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF |
| 0x00000020 | MQSO_MANAGED | MQOO_INQUIRE |
| 0x00002000 | MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING |

This means that you are opening the queue with the equivalent of the following options:

```
MQOO_BIND_AS_Q_DEF | MQOO_READ_AHEAD_AS_Q_DEF | MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQOO_INQUIRE |MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
```

This may or may not be what you want, but if nothing else it is extremely unclear how you have it currently.

---

Commit is only required if you do your GET under sync point.  This would mean you would add `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` or `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT` to your Get Message Options.  If you were to do this then the messages are not fully removed from the queue until you issue `MQQueueManager.Commit()`, it does not mean that other instances are able to read them at the same time, but if one of the following conditions happens the messages will be back on the queue available to be read by another instance of the application:

- The application crashes
- The application is disconnected from the queue manager
- The application issues `MQQueueManager.Backout()`

---

When you get a message without `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` or `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT` the message is immediately removed from the queue.  The message can never be read by another instance of the application.

---

In IBM MQ you can non-destructively read messages from a queue, this is called browsing the queue and is the result of opening the queue with `MQOO_BROWSE` and specifying one of the following get message options:

- `MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST`
- `MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT`
- `MQGMO_BROWSE_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR`

Most of the time the message you browsed can still be read by another application that opens the same queue.  You can however also add `MQGMO_LOCK` which will lock the message from being read by another application.  This allows you to later issue a destructive GET against the message you locked, several things will release the lock including issuing another GET call.

If you open the queue with one of the `MQOO_INPUT*` options and do not specify a `MQGMO_BROWSE*` option, then you are destructively reading messages from the queue.  This means the message will not be available for another application to read.

You can also issue a destructive GET with `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` for any message (persistent or non-persistent) (or `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT` if you only want it to apply to persistent messages) and the message will be read in a unit of work, it is no longer available for another application to get, but it is not removed from the queue until the unit of work is committed.

---

I could not find any specific statement from IBM that says the following:

> When you get a message without MQGMO_SYNCPOINT or MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT the message is immediately removed from the queue. The message can never be read by another instance of the application.

Here are some references that together paint this picture:

IBM Knowledge center page [IBM MQ>About IBM MQ>Introduction to IBM MQ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q001020_.htm)

> IBM MQ provides:
>
> - Qualities of service that provide once and once only delivery of messages to ensure messages will withstand application and system outages

IBM Knowledge center page [IBM MQ>Developing applications>Developing MQI applications with IBM MQ>Writing a procedural application for queuing>Committing and backing out units of work](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q096780_.htm)

> **Commit and back out**
>
> Similarly, when a program gets a message from a queue within a unit of work, that message remains on the queue until the program commits the unit of work, but the message is not available to be retrieved by other programs. The message is permanently deleted from the queue when the program commits the unit of work. If the program backs out the unit of work, IBM MQ restores the queue by making the messages available to be retrieved by other programs.
>
> **Syncpoint coordination, syncpoint, unit of work**
>
> *Syncpoint coordination* is the process by which units of work are either committed or backed out with data integrity.
> The decision to commit or back out the changes is taken, in the simplest case, at the end of a transaction. However, it can be more useful for an application to synchronize data changes at other logical points within a transaction. These logical points are called *syncpoints* (or *synchronization points* ) and the period of processing a set of updates between two syncpoints is called a *unit of work*. Several MQGET calls and MQPUT calls can be part of a single unit of work.

IBM Knowledge center page [IBM MQ>Developing applications>Developing MQI applications with IBM MQ>Writing a procedural application for queuing>Getting messages from a queue>Getting messages from a queue using the MQGET call](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026240_.htm)

> **Specifying MQGET options using the MQGMO structure**
>
> ...
>
> *Options*
> Within your code, you can select the options in any order; each option is represented by a bit in the *Options* field.
> The *Options* field controls:
>
> ...
>
> - Whether the get operation is included in a unit of work.
>
> ...
>
> - Whether the message is removed from the queue, or merely browsed

Comment: I'm a bit confused about subscription vs sync point modes, is it possible to consume messages in subscription mode in a way that each message is consumed by one and only one client. which parameters should I use then?

Comment: You are opening a queue not a subscription to a topic.  If you were opening a subscription to a topic you could issue gets under sync point. Open Options are used on queues. Subscription Options are used when subscribing to a topic. I added some more to my answer about not using sync point to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: ah, so I should've used AccessTopic() instead of AccessQueue() with those parameters, right? could you provide a link where I can read about the difference between these two? I thought topic is just and identificator of specific queue

Comment: reading IBM official documentation made me create this post, as each article there produces more questions than it answers.
> Topics are used for Pub/Sub. Queues are used for Point to Point.
 <-- this is something I can start from, thanks

Comment: you provided very valuable information, but the question is "should I call Commit() to guarantee that message is delivered once and only once to clients?", which is now split to two "<original question> in pub/sub scenario?" and "<original question> in Point to Point scenario"

Comment: thank you very much, Josh. could you provide a link to official documentation regarding "When you get a message without MQGMO_SYNCPOINT or MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT the message is **immediately removed from the queue**. The message can never be read by another instance of the application." if you please

Comment: I added some references at the end of my post, let me know if this provides what you are looking for.